Facing AWS issue while getting the data from the RDS
I am facing issue where
we have to fetch the data from RDS to our app, so we have used appsync and lambda to achieve that.
but i'm getting an issue while fetching the data and the error message goes like this:
"errors": [{"data": null, "errorInfo": null, "errorType": "400 Bad Request", "locations": [Array], "message": "RDSHttp:{\"message\":\"The schema parameter isn't supported.\"}"

we have 3 apps and we have dedicated apis endpoints for all the 3 apps in the AWS AppSync, but i'm unable to fetch the data from the RDS and facing this issue.
it was working yesterday, but from today morning i'm facing this issue, i has been 8 hrs since we are facing the issue, can anyone help..?
we tried all the possible ways of checking the configuration and backend files, but cant solve the issue..
